# How to fix shadow not casted to terrain when rendering using default and terrain shader (depth shader included)?

Tags: opengl, shaders, shadow-mapping

Given that I have the `TerrainShader` class and `DefaultShader` class. Also a FBO (Frame Buffer Object) shadow map

The `TerrainShader` has all the terrain, light, shadow related calculations. While the `DefaultShader` has the generic objects light, shadow related calculations.

I have successfully cast a directional shadow map when I only use `DefaultShader` alone with random cube objects and a plane. Now the problem was when I move or use a terrain instead of `TerrainShader`, the shadow is not cast in the terrain.

Question: Am I using the FBO the correct way or I am doing it wrong.

Solution Idea (Not yet applied)

- Merge terrain and default shader as one and create a flag if object or terrain will be rendered? (Still not sure if this is correct.)

Pseudocode (Current successful implementation)

- Create shadow map fbo
- Create default shader
- Create depth shader
- bind shadow map fbo
- clear depth
- render cubes & plane using depth shader (mvp)
- unbind shadow map fb
- clear color and depth
- render cubes & plane using default shader

Pseudocode (with Terrain shadow not working)

- Create shadow map fbo
- Create default shader
- Create terrain shader
- Create depth shader
- bind shadow map fbo
- clear depth
- render cubes & plane using depth shader (mvp) and exclude terrain
- unbind shadow map fb
- clear color and depth
- render cubes using default shader
- render terrain using terrain shader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turns out that I made a mistake, I have filtered out terrain in the list of entities. So by including the terrain again, the shadow map is now displayed in terrain